# Can we copy plugin files from another project if "cordova plugin add url" fails?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

Assuming the following fails

```
cordova plugin add https://git.apache.org/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Can we simply copy/paste files from another project which probably successfully installed it?
Or manually fetch this from a site or a project that didn't gitignored it?
How would that work.
What directory structure needs to be maintained?

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to **locate and fix the error** that is preventing the plugin installation. You can't just ignore the error and try installing any plugin version until the the error is magically gone, this is not the way to develop any reliable app.

**Your failure to install the plugin can come from either:**

- You are using outdated Cordova or cordova-android / cordova-ios
  platforms. Upgrade the CLI and the platforms (after doing this you
  MUST uninstall and reinstall ALL plugins!)
- Your app / project is already screwed up by other plugin(s) installed earlier. Deleting the entire platform folder and removing all plugins to reset the app structure should fix the problem.
- The plugin itself has an invalid structure. Most certainly this is impossible when you are referring to an official Apache plugin (InAppBrowser), so forget about this  possibility. Installation fails because something on your side is  wrong.

You could have provided the **output log** of the plugin installation process to help you fix this issue.